# could not find `options` in `mongodb` Rust Lang

Tags: mongodb, rust, actix-web

I am trying to connect to mongodb using in rust using mongodb library

here is the code

```
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};
use mongodb::{Client, options::ClientOptions};

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
// Parse a connection string into an options struct.
let mut client_options = ClientOptions::parse("mongodb://localhost:27017")?;

client_options.app_name = Some("My App".to_string());

let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;

for db_name in client.list_database_names(None)? {
    println!("{}", db_name);
}

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:3000")?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

I am getting following errors

1. error[E0432]: unresolved import `mongodb::options`
2. use mongodb::{Client, options::ClientOptions};
   |                       ^^^^^^^ could not find `options` in `mongodb`
3. let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::sync::Arc<r2d2_mongodb::mongodb::ClientInner>`

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you use the last version of mongodb ?

Comment: Using current version of mongodb.
**MongoDB shell version v4.2.5**

Comment: that not the version I want, what is your crate version https://crates.io/crates/mongodb ?

Comment: Yup that was the issue. I put start in the version. Later I changed it to version number it worked but facing different issue now.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put start in the version number in Cargo.toml.  Changing it to latest version number solved issue.